# Finding hexadecimal color code after applying opacity

Tags: css, colors, color-codes

I am trying to figure out a color code, hex or RGB, of a color after applying opacity.

E.g: I have an element with a `background-color` set to `#4d4d4d` in Hex format or `rgb(77,77,77)`.
Then I apply 50% opacity on the element.

How can I find the hex code of the *new color* displayed after applying the `opacity`. Lets suppose I am using a White background.

Comment: Hex doesn't just change.

Comment: Hex value doesn't change but the color appearance changes after applying opacity. So i need to find the hex code for this new color obtained after applying opacity.

Comment: @Kaiido I couldn't get my head around the math in that question. I wanted a simpler answer :)

Comment: What do you mean? The math is quite simple, and in the Q/A there are links to a wikipedia article and all the keywords you need in order to get your head over it.

Comment: @dup.titung what is the problem with `rgba()` format..?

Comment: @Bhuwan no any problem with rgba, it works fine. I just wanted to figure this out.

Comment: Screen shot and print into photoshop then use the color dropper to find the hex

Comment: @Tom That is what i used to do but someone told me that picked color differs according to different browser's render engine, also it varies across different design tool and operating systems. So picking color is not a reliable option. Do you agree?

Comment: @Bhuwan `rgba()` itself isnt a problem, but the actual showed color always depends on the background. So sometimes you want to get the actual showing color which is a result of the combination of the `rgba` and the background color. In the end, as @dup.titung stated, there is no real exact way to get those colors, i tend to use a colorpicker.